# Writing T instead of TRUE with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

By laziness, I often use the abbreviation `T` for `TRUE`. Here I am observing a weird behaviour with `dplyr`, where it is not always accepted.

This example crashes (``` incompatible value for ``na.rm`` argument ```):

```
df = head(iris)
mutate(df, n = n_distinct(Species, na.rm=T))
```

But these examples work:

```
mutate(df, n = n_distinct(Species, na.rm=TRUE))
df$n = n_distinct(df$Species, na.rm=T)
mutate(df, m = mean(Sepal.Length, na.rm=T))
```

Of course, the easy fix here is to avoid abbreviation and type `TRUE`. But this doesn't work either:

```
b = TRUE
mutate(df, n = n_distinct(Species, na.rm=b))
```

Is there any understandable explanation for this behaviour? Non-standard evaluation somehow? Knowing what to avoid would help me spend less time debugging my code.

Comment: It is always good to say `TRUE` instead of `T`.

Comment: OK, but what about the last example?

Comment: Probably you need `mutate(df, n = n_distinct(Species, na.rm=!!b))` as it may look for objects inside the environment.  the `!!` evaluation looks for objects outside the environment or similarly `mutate(df, n = n_distinct(Species, na.rm=!!T))` because it is looking for an object named `T`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was due to a bug, now fixed. Thanks to the Tidyverse team!

https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/3686

Answer (score 1):

It is always recommended to use the full name instead of abbreviation as `T` or `F` as this can lead to problems when an object exists of name `T` or `F`.  However, we can't assign a reserve word like `TRUE` as name

```
TRUE <- 1:5
```

> Error in TRUE <- 1:5 : invalid (do_set) left-hand side to assignment

Although a character string or backquotes can do this

```
`TRUE` <- 1:5 # but it is not recommended
```

---

One option to check for objects would be to use the bang-bang operator

```
out1 <- mutate(df, n = n_distinct(Species, na.rm=!!T))
out2 <- mutate(df, n = n_distinct(Species, na.rm=!!b))
out3 <- mutate(df, n = n_distinct(Species, na.rm=TRUE))
identical(out1, out3)
#[1] TRUE
identical(out1, out2)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications and for mentioning the bang-bang. What I still don't understand is why `n_distinct`has no access to `T` which is in the base environment. And in between, I noticed that `f=n_distinct ; mutate(df, n = f(Species, na.rm=T))` does work... This is even more puzzling.